# Mysterious behavior of ajax jquery request inside jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, tabs, request

I have jquery tabs created and inside of a tab there is a form where at the bottom of it, there is this button.

`<button id="submitForm" onclick="formSubmition();">Submit</button>`

Here are the headers

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

formSubmition() exists in lib.js file and here is its code

```
function formSubmition(){

    $recId              = $("#recId").val();
    $collectionDate     = $("#collectionDate").val();
    $collectorsName     = $("#collectorsName").val();
    $donorsName         = $("#donorsName").val();
    $sciName            = $("#sciName").val();
    $family             = $("#family").val();
    $comName            = $("#comName").val();
    $variety            = $("#variety").val();
    $area               = $("#area").val();
    $location           = $("#location").val();
    $altitude           = $("#altitude").val();
    $geoOrientation     = $("#geoOrientation").val();
    $geoCoordinates     = $("#geoCoordinates").val();
    $soilDescription    = $("#soilDescription").val();
    $habitatDescription = $("#habitatDescription").val();
    $plantPopulation    = $("#plantPopulation").val();
    $photoDate          = $("#photoDate").val();
    $photoId            = $("#photoId").val();
    $photoComments      = $("#photoComments").val();    
    $soilTaken          = 0;
    $seedQuantity       = $("#seedQuantity").val();
    $plantQuantity      = $("#plantQuantity").val();
    $graftQuantity      = $("#graftQuantity").val();
    $moreInfo           = $("#moreInfo").val();

    if($('#soilTaken').is(':checked'))          // Checking if Checkbox was checked.
        $soilTaken  = 1;


    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        url: 'classes/classController.php',
        data: {method: "recNewPlant", recId: $recId, collectionDate: $collectionDate, collectorsName: $collectorsName, donorsName: $donorsName, sciName: $sciName, family: $family, comName: $comName, variety: $variety, area: $area, location: $location, altitude: $altitude, geoOrientation: $geoOrientation, geoCoordinates: $geoCoordinates, soilDescription: $soilDescription, habitatDescription: $habitatDescription, plantPopulation: $plantPopulation, photoDate: $photoDate, photoId: $photoId, photoComments: $photoComments, soilTaken: $soilTaken, seedQuantity: $seedQuantity, plantQuantity: $plantQuantity, graftQuantity: $graftQuantity, moreInfo: $moreInfo},
        contentType: ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(json){

          if(json.status == '1'){
              alert("Added!");
          }else{
            alert("Problema!");
          }
        }
    });

}
```

The problem is that i have use this method so many times but this is the first time that it behaves like this. What i mean. If i press the button , nothing happens at most of the time and some times (rare) in chromium only (not in firefox) it sends a request to the server and it returns "Problema" messagage.

I ve erased the cache of two browsers but nothing changed. Also i'm using OWASP ZAP to see the traffic and indeed , doesn't send any POST request. I thought that maybe the tabs cause that problem but i cannot find the why.

Here is the way i setup tabs:

`$("#mainTabs").tabs();`

Comment: post your server side code

Comment: classController.php http://pastebin.com/jEs8b697                          records.class.php http://pastebin.com/D7p9ttUY

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check

```
if(json.status == '1'){
              alert("Added!");
          }else{
            alert("Problema!");
          }
```

only if the request is success success function() gets executed

Try this

If to check some error in ajax call,I have added an `error:function()`,which will alert the error if error occurs

```
function formSubmition(){

    $recId              = $("#recId").val();
    $collectionDate     = $("#collectionDate").val();
    $collectorsName     = $("#collectorsName").val();
    $donorsName         = $("#donorsName").val();
    $sciName            = $("#sciName").val();
    $family             = $("#family").val();
    $comName            = $("#comName").val();
    $variety            = $("#variety").val();
    $area               = $("#area").val();
    $location           = $("#location").val();
    $altitude           = $("#altitude").val();
    $geoOrientation     = $("#geoOrientation").val();
    $geoCoordinates     = $("#geoCoordinates").val();
    $soilDescription    = $("#soilDescription").val();
    $habitatDescription = $("#habitatDescription").val();
    $plantPopulation    = $("#plantPopulation").val();
    $photoDate          = $("#photoDate").val();
    $photoId            = $("#photoId").val();
    $photoComments      = $("#photoComments").val();    
    $soilTaken          = 0;
    $seedQuantity       = $("#seedQuantity").val();
    $plantQuantity      = $("#plantQuantity").val();
    $graftQuantity      = $("#graftQuantity").val();
    $moreInfo           = $("#moreInfo").val();

    if($('#soilTaken').is(':checked'))          // Checking if Checkbox was checked.
        $soilTaken  = 1;


    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        url: 'classes/classController.php',
        data: {method: "recNewPlant", recId: $recId, collectionDate: $collectionDate, collectorsName: $collectorsName, donorsName: $donorsName, sciName: $sciName, family: $family, comName: $comName, variety: $variety, area: $area, location: $location, altitude: $altitude, geoOrientation: $geoOrientation, geoCoordinates: $geoCoordinates, soilDescription: $soilDescription, habitatDescription: $habitatDescription, plantPopulation: $plantPopulation, photoDate: $photoDate, photoId: $photoId, photoComments: $photoComments, soilTaken: $soilTaken, seedQuantity: $seedQuantity, plantQuantity: $plantQuantity, graftQuantity: $graftQuantity, moreInfo: $moreInfo},
        contentType: ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(json){
             alert(success);
        },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This work, make sure your json is formatted correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $recId              = $("#recId").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {method: "recNewPlant", recId: $recId},
        dataType: "json",
    })
    .done(function(json) {console.debug(json);})
    .fail(function() {console.debug('problema');}); 
    return true;
  });
});
```

php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('status' => 1));
```

Comment: I don't think that the problem is at `header('Content-type: application/json');` I have so many times use this code i post but i cannot understand what is going wrong now.

Comment: I was getting only *problema* until I didn't used `json_encode` because it was malformed. Maybe you should post also your returning json

Comment: `json_encode` may also fail depending on the content of the fields, in your `records.class.php` check the result `!== FALSE` and eventually use `json_last_error()` to check why and where http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Oh! i'm gonna loose my mind. The mysterious thing returned!:p Lets forget for a while the json dataType and make it more simple. Here is the new code of the two files http://pastebin.com/FnTk9AB6. Now when im running this , im getting once an alert with "Hello" in it and once  with [object Object]error in it. I noticed that when im erasing the `?` from the url (that it gets it from pressing the button) there are more chances (not allways) to print out the "Hello" word. It's very curious all this. Also i ve noticed that maybe it wants some time to re-alert the "Hello". Pfff i don't know.

Comment: Hmmm just a new edit. I add `async: false` and seems to work. I will investigate it better and i will post the answer if it is right.

Answer (score 0):

And yes. That was the problem. Had to replace `async:true` into `async:false`

Comment: This isn't an answer, this is a workaround for your very specific case, the `.ajax` method is supposed to work with both sync or async, and if it doesn't mean you have a problem at some other level